# Is empty string allocated memory in Java?

Tags: java, string

I think empty string is allocated, so I tried. Is that so ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An empty string is a string with length = 0. It is allocated in a memory block to store the variable.

Comment: Nit pick: The String is *not* "allocated in a memory block to store the variable". It is [*interned*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) (nowhere near the variable and long before memory for the variable itself has been allocated) and the variable is assigned a reference to the interned String.

Comment: The allocation of the String object and the allocation of the variable are two different matters.

Comment: @Bohemian Not true in the case shown, where `new String` is invoked explicitly.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it is true for `a` and the exact same String object is passed to `new String("")`

Comment: @Bohemian Correct, but the object referred to by `b` is not `a`.